# Why is aluminum oxide resistant to corrosion?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, metal, corrosion

It is common knowledge that aluminum is relatively resistant to corrosion due to its tough oxide layer. The ultrathin (1 nm even) layer is impervious to water and oxygen. What I can't figure out is, why? What makes $\ce{Al2O3}$ so strong compared to $\ce{Na2O}$ or $\ce{MgO}$? My theory is that the aluminum oxide molecules are tightly bound together due to the high charge density of aluminum ions, and this forms a physical barrier where water and oxygen molecules can't come through. This will explain why this only applies to aluminum, as its small size and 3+ charge should make its charge density amongst the highest known. I can't find anything corroborating this claim, though.

Comment: While waiting for an answer you may want to search for "passivation" and either spelling of aluminium on this site, as there are many relevant anwers, for instance: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/125691/will-aluminum-continue-to-corrode-after-its-surface-is-oxidized/

Comment: Also Al is not unique in this regard.

Comment: @Alchimista - true, but only 3 elements have a self-limiting oxidation layer so it is close to unique...

Comment: @JonCuster ... chromium, titanium, and nothing else?

Comment: @Karl - aluminum, silicon, and beryllium (or boron - I really don't deal with those). Neither Cr or Ti self-limit.

Comment: @JonCuster Ah, you wrote "element", I read "metal". ;-) What exactly do you mean by "self-limit", i.e. why does that exclude Cr and Ti?

Comment: Self passivating is the more proper term perhaps. A clean silicon surface exposed to air grows a passivating oxide layer. It stops somewhere around 1.5nm in thickness and does not grow any further (under steam at 1000C you can grow it thicker). Similarly aluminum in air gets a 5nm thick oxide film, and it stops growing. Oxide layers on most other metals will keep growing under STP conditions, it just slows down. But you wait a few years and it will be thicker. Not silicon or aluminum.

Comment: You might also look up the chemical resistance of sapphire or alundum.