# Is using oxidized aluminium baking forms safe?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

My apologies in advance if this is not the best forum for this kind of question.

Recently, I've bought a few non-anodized aluminium bread-baking forms, such as this one:

[image]

As you can see, there is already some discoloration on them when they come from the shop. My knowledge of chemistry is rudimentary but I presume it is an oxidized aluminum layer (do correct me if I am wrong here).

Now, my wife decided it is a good idea to wash these forms in a dishwasher. The forms became even darker, becoming rather gray over their entire area. There are a lof of posts on various forums and blogs telling you to not put aluminium cookware in dishwashers, and most of them go on about how to remove the oxidized layer.

For my purposes, I do not care how it looks. I would like to know whether it is safe to bake bread in those (post-dishwasher and without removing the oxide layer). There is very little information about this, as the online discussions revolve mostly about removing the gray layer. I've read someone saying that the oxide layer can even be beneficial as it might prevent aluminium leaking into food. This does make sense, presuming that the oxide itself is not harmful and does not leak. Could someone comment on this please? Any reference to scientific literature would be a bonus.

As a backstory, the reason I bought these forms is because they are traditionally used for making specific sorts of rye sourdoughs in the Baltic region. So I'd like to give them a go before buying more modern (and more boring) stainless steel forms.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141001/why-is-aluminum-oxide-resistant-to-corrosion just to say that Al object always have a layer of oxide onto them. All the discussions about cookware discoloration etc are basically based on aesthetic. There are not really existing ruined pans etc, at least they perfectly keep their function. We don't give health advices, this is to say that your form is substantially the same independently of the look. Anodization is just a way to control the film of oxide. It forms anyway and stain or discoloration is just matter of optical phenomena.

Comment: Here is an answer to the title question :  the alumina layer is safe. Even if you swallow a bit, this oxide will not react with the acid in the stomach, and the whole stuff will go through the intestine without being modified.

Comment: @Maurice unfortunately I can not under vote a comment. I invite OP to read my comment as the answer is it in there. Plus the obvious fact that if something is in use as cookware since long time there cannot be evident acute or long term effects by just ruining it's appearance.

Comment: @ Alchimista. Sorry ! I do not understand your comment. All I have said is that aluminum oxide is not soluble in the dilute HCl solution in the stomach. What do you have against it ? Of course, your comment is valid, but it is not in the same domain as mine.

Comment: @Maurice because I can't see how subnanoparticles of Al oxide won't dissolve in the stomach. The fact remains that we know it is safe to use Al cookware. All the rest, can eventually shorten of a good looking pan. That will keep functioning for years of mishandling. This is even no to say that we don't get Al intake by the cookware, but just to put the issue in the right perspective.

Answer (score 1):

In accord with this forum's policy on not providing health advice, I  will just comment on the chemistry surrounding any created Al3+ interacting with the superoxide radical anion (which is incidentally, present in the human body). As a source, here is a 2014 article by Tushar Kanti Das, et al, published in *Archives of Neuroscience*, [available here](https://sites.kowsarpub.com/ans/articles/60038.html).

The authors explicitly references, in Figure 4, “Formation of Aluminum Superoxide Semi reduced Radical Ion and Aluminum Superoxide Complex (43)”, with described reactions proceeding as follows (also adopting notation and water complexing from yet another article):

$$\ce{[Al(H2O)4](3+) + O2•− <-> [Al(O2•−)(H2O)4](2+) }$$

$$\ce{[Al(O2•−)(H2O)4](2+) + Fe(3+) --> O2 + [Al(H2O)4](3+) + Fe(2+)}$$

And, in acidic conditions:

$$\ce{[Al(H2O)4](3+) + O2•− + H+ <-> [Al(O2•−)(H+)H2O)4](3+)}$$

$$\ce{[Al(O2•−)(H+)H2O)4](3+) + [Al(O2•−)(H+)H2O)4](3+) --> 2 [Al(H2O)4](3+) + H2O2 + O2}$$

where the above chemistry suggests a role for Al3+ in possibly assisting with the subsequent production of miscellaneous powerful radicals associated with a [Fenton reaction](https://meridian.allenpress.com/radiation-research/article-abstract/145/5/523/40315)  as sourced from an iron ion presence (as in blood).

Now, as to the possible originating source of Al3+ itself, in the particular context of baking with Aluminum pans, and further washing said aluminum ware in a dishwasher also employing Baking Soda, is that the latter NaHCO3 on warming in aqueous solutions, apparently will attack Al metal, commencing with the reaction:

$$\ce{ NaHCO3 + H2O + Heat --> NaOH + H2O + CO2 }$$

And further, to [quote Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_aluminate#:%7E:text=Sodium%20aluminate%20is%20also%20formed,O%20%E2%86%92%202NaAlO2%20%2B%203H):

> Sodium aluminate is also formed by the action of sodium hydroxide on elemental aluminium which is an amphoteric metal. The reaction is highly exothermic once established and is accompanied by the rapid evolution of hydrogen gas. The reaction is sometimes written as:
> $$\ce{ 2Al + 2NaOH + 2H2O → 2NaAlO2 + 3H2 }$$
> however, the species produced in solution is likely to contain the [Al(OH)4]− ion or perhaps the [Al(H2O)2(OH)4]− ion.[6]

This problem with Aluminum ware is well known (see warnings, for example, [here](https://worldofpans.com/why-do-aluminum-pans-get-discolored-in-the-dishwasher/), and [also here](https://dishwashingsecrets.com/aluminum-in-dishwasher-toxic/)).

I hope this, in part, advanced chemistry presentation nevertheless is of assistance in answering your question "Is using oxidized aluminium baking forms safe?".

Comment: As I mentioned in the question part, my knowledge of chemistry is quite rudimentary (from a limited secondary school program some 30 years ago). Would you care to summarize your reply in key take-aways in layman's terms? I totally get the policy of not providing advice on health matters, though I hope that calling out obvious toxins in still within the policy. I think the key question is whether dishwasher added something on top of the "normal" oxidation process in the course of use. These forms have been used for half a century in multiple countries, so normal use should be OK.Cheers!

Comment: I believe the last reference I cited (repeated here https://dishwashingsecrets.com/aluminum-in-dishwasher-toxic/ ) does a fair job in expressing and addressing your concerns. Note: this reference uses bold letters on the point of  using dishwasher safe detergents. Cheers!

Comment: To continue my comment, surprisingly, the cited reference even brings up the case of muffin pans!

Comment: I am afraid it does not address my concerns at all. It deals with whether it is safe to put aluminium cookware in the dishwasher (e.g., to avoid discoloration). It does not say anything if the oxide/discoloration itself will affect the food. Aside from "I think baking cakes [...] in aluminum dishes are acceptable". The question was whether oxidation produced by the dishwasher is OK. There is ample scientific evidence regular aluminum cookware is fine. Also, judging by its level and style of English, the source does not inspire confidence, I'm afraid.

Comment: I am referring to the 2nd referenced cookware article which does make an opinion-based health assertion, not necessarily mine, or in accord with this forum. Note: unlike copper cookware toxicity, no need to be afraid of being immediately poisoned!  At worst, it is more of a longer-term opinion of possible ascribed health problems, which you may (or never) experience. Certainly, one can always more safely use steel, but it does not distribute heat well. If you are concerned or which to be very cautious, use NEW coated cookware and discard quickly if the coating is damaged. Cheers!